# image carousel won't infinitely loop in reverse

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am creating an HTML5 image carousel with three images. The transitions are done with TweenMax and TimeLine. I have two click events, one for next image and one for previous image, the next image function runs properly and is an infinite loop but the previous function stops after it goes through the images once. here is the code.

HTML:

```
<div id="expanded-state">
    <div id="expanded-exit"></div>
    <div id="close-btn"></div>
    <button id="arrow-prev"></button>
    <button id="arrow-next"></button>
    <div id="theater">
        <div class="theater"></div>
        <div class="theater"></div>
        <div class="theater"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="cta"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.theater {
    width: 970px;
    height: 345px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.theater:nth-child(1){
    background: url(theater-01.jpg);
}

.theater:nth-child(2){
    background: url(theater-02.jpg);
}

.theater:nth-child(3){
    background: url(theater-03.jpg);
}
```

JS:

```
var $slides = $(".theater");
var currentSlide = 0;

function addListeners() {
    arrowPrev.addEventListener('click', theaterScrollPrev);
    arrowNext.addEventListener('click', theaterScrollNext);
}

function theaterScrollNext() {

    tm.to( $slides.eq(currentSlide), 0.5, {left:"-970px"} );        

    if (currentSlide < $slides.length - 1) {
        currentSlide++;
    }
    else {
        currentSlide = 0;
    }

    tm.fromTo( $slides.eq(currentSlide), 0.5, {left: "970px"}, {left:"0px"} );
}

function theaterScrollPrev() {

    tm.to( $slides.eq(currentSlide), 0.5, {left:"970px"} );     

    if (currentSlide < $slides.length - 1) {
        currentSlide--;
    }
    else {
        currentSlide = 0;
    }

    tm.fromTo( $slides.eq(currentSlide), 0.5, {left: "-970px"}, {left:"0px"});
}
```

Comment: extending my question a little.  jQuery is so bulky, so I was wondering if there was a vanilla js way to do this same function. My js chops aren't that great yet. thanks.

Comment: You should be animating the `x` property and not the `left` property so you can animate on a sub-pixel level. CSS position offsets like `left` only animate on a pixel level. Animating `x` and `y` will take advantage of the hardware acceleration. Animating the CSS position offsets like `left` will trigger layout and not give you silky smooth animations. http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should fix it but tell me if it does not

```
    function theaterScrollPrev() {
    console.log('previous clicked')
    tm.to( $slides.eq(currentSlide), 0.5, {left:"970px"} );     

    if (currentSlide <= 0) {
        currentSlide = $slides.length -1;
  } else {
    currentSlide--;
    }

      tm.fromTo( $slides.eq(currentSlide), 0.5, {left: "-970px"}, {left:"0px"} );
}
```

[Codepen Fixed](http://codepen.io/Riddell/pen/GZVazv)

Comment: thanks @Riddell, but that did not fix it. The first slide shows up on page load but when you click previous it goes to a blank frame.

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle so I can try myself please Ryan? It would help a lot to understand the issue.

Comment: No Problem! Glad I Could Help. @RyanCopeland